# Ansible read csv that has spaces in column names

Tags: ansible

I am trying to read csv in ansible and the file they are sending me has spaces in column names. Example:

| User name | Password | Home phone number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sampleuser | fksdakfjdk | 54545646 |

I have tried to read it using escape symbols and similar but keep getting error. Since i am new to ansible maybe its something obvious that escapes me.
any help is appreciated.

Edit:

this is something similar to what i need

```
- name: Read users from CSV file and return a dictionary
  read_csv:
    path: credentials.csv
  register: users
  delegate_to: localhost

- name:  test   
  command: mkdir /home/{{ item.['User name'] }}
  loop: users.list
```

Comment: How are you trying to read it? Please show us an example playbook that exhibits whatever problem you've encountered.

Comment: i have edited it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems with your playbook.

The first is that you have:

```
loop: user.list
```

This is trying to iterate over the literal string value `user.list`, which is going to fail. You should have:

```
loop: "{{ user.list }}"
```

Secondly, you have written:

```
{{ item.['User name'] }}
```

This looks like an attempt to combine the dot-style notation (`item.key`) with the bracket style notation (`item[key]`). You should write:

```
{{ item['User name'] }}
```

Comment: thank you wanted to finish this fast and started making more and more errors... works now like a charm

Answer (score 1):

To read a dict with ansible, 2 possibility

- variable.key
- variable['key']

Use the second

```
- ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: variable['Home phone number']
```